# How to download a shared item on google colab using wget?

Tags: google-colaboratory, wget

I have a shared link like the below

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tfBFavijh4UTG4cGqIKwhcklLXUDuY0D/view

but I am unable to download it google colab using the command

```
wget https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tfBFavijh4UTG4cGqIKwhcklLXUDuY0D/view
```

Few suggestion on the internet were to use the below command

```
wget --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILEID' -O FILENAME
```

but this didn't work. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use gdown

```
!gdown --id 1tfBFavijh4UTG4cGqIKwhcklLXUDuY0D
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a retry option after certificate check to the command. An example below

```
wget --no-check-certificate -r 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1tfBFavijh4UTG4cGqIKwhcklLXUDuY0D' -O FILENAME.zip
```

Comment: I got this error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Answer (score 0):

Works for me adding "&confirm=t", so:
wget --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/ucexport=download&id=FILEID&confirm=t' -O FILENAME